# Enable rewrite mode in xampp in localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp, localhost

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit (maybe this is not important) and I have xampp installed. 
In my htdocs/ directory I have more then one project. Now, for one of them (let say htdocs/test/) i have created vhost called "example". And that works fine...
Inside dir /test/ i have .htaccess file with this code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /test
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)\.(js|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)$
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Here I want to redirect all traffic to my `index.php` page because I'm using here some my system for whole project which starts from index page. In `httpd.conf`, I enabled `rewrite_module` and also inside

```
<Directory "C:/Program Files/xampp/htdocs">
```

I've changed the `AllowOverride` directive to `All`.

Now, as I told, when I'm trying to access to my project with created vhost "example" this works fine. But when I try to access to some other project inside my htdocs dir, I get an Internal Server Error (HTTP 500) and this message in log file:

```
[Thu Nov 15 11:07:12 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Also, if I type in URL `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`, I get my project defined with "example" vhost...
This is pretty much confusing, can anyone help?

Comment: If you have Apache 2.2, setting LogLevel to debug won't help. To start getting your head around it, you'll need to add these directives inside the vhost <Directory> directive:
`RewriteLog "logs/myvhost.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 1`; the rewriteloglevel tells apache how much to be verbose and goes from 0 (nothing) to 9 (everything). Change myvhost.rewrite.log according to your needs.

Comment: Which dir is the DocumentRoot of the vhost?

Comment: Please can you provide your vhosts config for `test` and also another project?

Comment: Try adding a `[L]` directive to your `RewriteRule` to stop processing. It sounds link your root and subdirectory htaccess files are conflicting, perhaps exclude the subdirectories from your root rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your root and subdirectory htaccess files are in conflict. Exclude your subdirectory processing from your root htaccess file, and make sure to use the [`[L]`ast rule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) directive.

**Root HTACCESS** - exclude "test" subdirectory, use `[L]`ast rule directive.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)\.(js|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)$

# exclude the "test" subdirectory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(test)/?

# add [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

**"Test" Subdirectory HTACCESS** - use `[L]`ast rule directive.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)\.(js|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)$

# add [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```